# Zeta function of $x^4 + y^4 - z^4 = 0 $ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

This is Problem $14$ from Chapter $11$ of Ireland Rosen.

Given $p \equiv 1 (4) $ and the curve $x^4 + y^4 =1$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, I need to find the number of projective points in the hypersurface and calculate the zeta function in terms of $\pi = -J(\chi, \chi^2)$ where $\chi$ is a charcter of order $4$.

I know I need to look at the projective hypersurface of the homogeneous polynomial $x^4 + y^4 - z^4=0$. But I am getting lost in the notations and I am not able to reach an answer. Could anyone please outline the solution or link a solution to the problem?